# Get row differences in a Dataframe with Multiindex groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have have a df of the form as below. I would like to compute the differences between the rows in **each multi index group** and store the output in a different column e.g. difference.

My DF

```
            values
first second
bar   one     10
      two     20

baz   one     15
      two     30

foo   one     25
      two     40

qux   one     05
      two     10
```

**Expected Output:**

```
            values  difference
first second
bar   one     10      NaN
      two     20      10

baz   one     15      NaN
      two     30      15

foo   one     25      NaN
      two     40       15

qux   one     05      NaN
      two     10      05
```

I'm very new to Pandas and the code I have runs throughout the df disregarding the multiindexes.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a `groupby` on the first level:

```
df['difference'] = df.groupby(['first']).diff()
```